# "Giant Pixel", low-energy component?

Tags: components

I'm really not sure if this is the best place to ask this, but I'm working on a project that requires a sort of 'giant pixel' of sorts, maybe about 4"x4", that can either be dark or light, and can maintain that state with low power (or no power at all, if possible, as in e-ink and things like that).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what kind of component can fulfill this?

Comment: With the information you give us right now, I'd say electronic photo frame with custom made pictures.

Comment: @jippie Those take power. The best answer seems to be in the question, an e-ink display?

Comment: Flip dot's only use power to change state, but I don't know in what sizes they come and if they can show more than 2 colors. Of course you can combine them into a larger one.

Comment: Mechanical pixels.  Remember the old displays in the airports?  They had 5x7 pixelated characters.  Each pixel was a plate (green on one side, black on the other), which could be flipped.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I believe you are referring to flip dot's. http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=flip%20dot&tbs=imgo:1&biw=1224&bih=679&sei=L87YUJTJKOic0QWAnIGYDQ#hl=en&tbo=d&tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=flip+dot+display&oq=flip+dot+display&gs_l=img.3..0j0i24l2.155571.156631.0.156959.8.2.0.6.6.0.106.189.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.1.F9qCqtQiMRY&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=693da1bd2f506f4a&bpcl=40096503&biw=1224&bih=679

Comment: @jippie  Yes.  I didn't know this is called Flip Dot.

Comment: The mechanical solution is the best for sure, especially if you don't need to toggle the pixel very often. You just need a piece of wood/plastic. To operate it a RC servo is a great option in my opinion, you can also turn off the servo with a mosfet for super power saving.

Comment: Just to throw in some keywords here: [Electrochromism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochromism) and/or [Smart Glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass). The further is used for instance in automatic rear-view mirrors or in those fancy high-tech sun roofs in cars, which are basically single "giant pixels".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Flip dots** only use current when flipping and are easily combined to a into a larger panel.

[image: Flip dot display]

On [the FlipDots webpage](http://www.flipdots.com/how-it-works.html) it is explained how it works.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-dot_display or this is a cool (slightly off topic) little video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3jkoIyJgoc

Comment: http://www.flipdots.com/how-it-works.html

Comment: I like this video of something very similar.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZysu9QcceM

Comment: @DavidKessner - wow, that is pretty cool.

Comment: I ended up just using a single LED and a box with cloudy glass but this solution -- besides being super cool -- will definitely be useful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is the type of thing you are looking for (as it doesn't meet the low power requirements), but adafruit do some cool [EL panels](http://www.adafruit.com/products/625) that might be worth checking out:

[image]

There is also, "Smart Glass", but I'm not sure where you can actually get hold of it from in small quantities (you can get samples from some [companies](https://sites.google.com/a/glasnovations.com/smart-glass-switchable-glass/products?gclid=CJWwgriItLQCFczHtAodrGoAqw))

Another possibility is [making your own](http://translate.google.co.uk/translate?u=http://fluessigkristalle.com/selbstbau.htm&sl=de&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8) :-s